# npm install gives CERT_HAS_EXPIRED error for sap-cloud-sdk

Tags: npm, sap-cloud-sdk, npm-registry

I tried to install the following and got the following error.

```
npm install @sap/cloud-sdk-op-vdm-material-stock-service

npm ERR! code CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
npm ERR! errno CERT_HAS_EXPIRED
npm ERR! request to https://npm.sap.com/@sap%2fcloud-sdk-op-vdm-material-stock-service failed, reason: certificate has expired

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-22T12_29_49_566Z-debug.log
```

Any common reason.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is about the registry `https://npm.sap.com/` you used.

You can run the command to switch to public npm registry:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Maybe you can also check your `.npmrc` file and remove all registry configuration related to the `https://npm.sap.com/`.
By default, you should then use the public registry `http://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Comment: How do l check the .npmrc file so that l can remove all registry configurations related to the https://npm .sap.com/?

Comment: Please check the doc regarding the .npmrc file: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/npmrc. It shows the potential locations. If you dont have them, then the default value is used.